# Hide table within Div

Tags: jquery

I'm used the below code to hide all Paras which contain a keyword 'text'

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("div p:contains('text')").parent('div').hide();
});
```

I would like to know if this works for table rows? I want to hide all divs under which the table rows contain a keyword.

Please help.

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Comment: Have you tried the same with tables?

Comment: I tried with TR but it doesn't hide the rows with keywords.

Answer (score 2):

I think it will be better written as

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("div:has(tr:contains('text'))").hide();
});
```

Comment: Thanks Arun but for some reason the TR don't hide. Actually this DIV is dynamically placed in an aspx page. May be that's the reason.

Comment: @Krishnam in that case the code has to executed after the div is added